# Exercise 2.6.6 Introduction to Real Analysis by Jiri Lebl

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Expand $\frac{x}{4-x^2}$ as a power series around $x_0 = 0$ and compute its radius of convergence.

$\frac{x}{4-x^2} = x \frac1{4-x^2} = \frac{x}4 \frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{4}} = \frac{x}4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{x^2}{4})^n \text{(assuming that} \frac{x^2}{4} <1) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{4^{n+1}} x^{2n+1}$.

I am stuck here. How can I proceed from here to get the power series : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x - 0)^n$?

Comment: You are almost done. The $a_n$ will be piecewise defined, depending on if $n$ is even or odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

$$\frac1{1-t} = 1+ t+t^2+t^3+\>...$$

to expand

$$\frac{x}{4-x^2}=\frac x4\cdot\frac1{1-(\frac x2)^2}
=\frac x4\cdot \left( 1 + (\frac x2)^2 + (\frac x2)^4+(\frac x2)^6+\>... \right)$$
$$=\frac x{2^2} + \frac {x^3}{2^4} + \frac {x^5}{2^6}+\frac {x^7}{2^8}+\>... 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{[1-(-1)^k]}{2^{k+2}}x^k $$

Its radius of convergence is $(\frac x2)^2 < 1$, or $|x|<2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{x}{4-x^2} = \dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}} - \dfrac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}}\right)$. Note that this way of expanding is essentially the same as the one you have. But going this way helps you not only to keep track of the coefficients $a_n$ better, but to write a formula for the $a_n$ easier as well.